# custom jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want jquery tabs like [Click](http://i55.tinypic.com/70cs1ewrweu.jpg)

It will animate each of the Questions in order using a slide up & slide down jquery animation.

1) Display Content

2)Then activate the “Question 1” Tab  by showing the red hover button” and at the same time slide up displaying its contents over

3)After 5 seconds activate the “Question 2” Tab by showing the blue hover button and at the same time slide up displaying its contents over

4)After 5 seconds activate the “Question 3” Tab by showing the green hover button and at the same time slide up displaying its contents over

Is there available any plugin same like it?

**Thanks in advance**

*W3father*

Answer (score 0):

Select any of these [jQuery tab plugins](http://www.extratuts.com/amazing-jquery-tabs-tutorials) and customize according to your need with the help of **CSS and logic.**

**ALL D BEST**